# How to calculate a list based on multiple results from items in a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list `A=[a,b,c,d]`. I need to calculate a new list `B` based on operations between each item in `A`.

```
B= [a, b-(a), c-(a+(b-a)), d-(a+(b-a)+(c-(a+(b-a)))) ]
```

Is there a Pythonic way of doing this? List A is not always a 4 item list, so the solution needs to be generalizable to lists of arbitrary length. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the expression for your list can be simplified to:

```py
B = [a, b-a, c-b, d-c]
```

With this in mind, we can use a list comprehension:

```py
[y - x for x, y in zip([0] + data, data)]
```

---

For example,

```py
data = [1, 2, 7, 6]
result = [y - x for x, y in zip([0] + data, data)]
print(result)
```

outputs:

```py
[1, 1, 5, -1]
```

Comment: How do you know they cancel out? [They might not](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P1FHIUlHIVlHIUXBVsFQB4xSdY0MoBRXQVFmXomGempFQWpyiZW6jkI0SIeuRqImUBeQ0tZI0k3UBHJS4BxtDSQJTU2FWE2YKUWpxaU5SKYkgsxIAulNjtX8/x8A).

Answer (score 1):

All your terms cancel out (`c-(a+(b-a))` simplifies to `c - b`, `d-(a+(b-a)+(c-(a+(b-a))))` simplifies to `d - c`), so the real algorithm here is that each term is equal to the matching term minus the prior term. This simplifies things dramatically:

```
B = [A[0]]  # Initial term has no prior to subtract from it
B += [x - y for x, y in zip(A[1:], A)]  # All other terms computed by subtracting term n - 1 from term n
```

If you want to one-line this (ignoring imports) you can stick a virtual `0` in to get the results for the first element without explicitly special-casing it:

```
from itertools import chain  # At top of file

B = [x - y for x, y in zip(A, chain([0], A))]
```

If you love using `map` and friends for microoptimizations, you could replace the latter with:

```
from operator import sub  # At top of file

B = [*map(sub, A, chain([0], A))]
```

and push all the work to the C layer (no per-element bytecode execution).

Comment: How do you know they cancel out? [They might not](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P1FHIUlHIVlHIUXBVsFQB4xSdY0MoBRXQVFmXomGempFQWpyiZW6jkI0SIeuRqImUBeQ0tZI0k3UBHJS4BxtDSQJTU2FWE2YKUWpxaU5SKYkgsxIAulNjtX8/x8A).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Heh. Sure, floating point is the devil (I've said it before, I'll say it again). That said, the results from simplifying the logical math are in fact more correct (from a mathematical perspective) than what you get from the unsimplified expression; the unsimplified expression is getting different results due to insufficient precision on C's `double` type. It's fairly unusual that you *want* the flaws in floating point to make your result diverge from the mathematically correct answer, but I suppose in extremely weird cases it might come up.

Comment: The "simplified" version *might* be more "correct" depending on the types and the intention. But it deviates from the reference code not just for `float` but also for example for `Counter`, see the tests in my answer. Or even consider some custom type. The question doesn't say it has anything to do with nice numbers. The only number appearing in the entire question is the "4" referring to the list length. All we know about the values is that they support `+` and `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that don't assume that things "cancel out" (because that is wrong already for standard types like `float` and `Counter`, as shown below).

If I understand the pattern correctly, the first B-value shall be the first A-value and then each next B-value shall always be the next A-value minus the sum of all previous B-values. One way to do that:

```
B = []
for a in A:
    if not B:
        b = sumB = a
    else:
        b = a - sumB
        sumB = sumB + b
    B.append(b)
```

Fun one using `itertools.accumulate` and `operator.sub`:

```
B = A[:1]
B += map(sub, A[1:], accumulate(B))
```

Tests:

```
                        A = [31, 41, 59, 26]
reference                   [31, 10, 18, -33]
subtract_neighbors  correct [31, 10, 18, -33]
loop                correct [31, 10, 18, -33]
fun                 correct [31, 10, 18, -33]

                        A = [1, 1, 1e-20, 1e-20]
reference                   [1, 0, -1.0, 1e-20]
subtract_neighbors  wrong   [1, 0, -1.0, 0.0]
loop                correct [1, 0, -1.0, 1e-20]
fun                 correct [1, 0, -1.0, 1e-20]

                        A = [Counter(), Counter({None: 1}), Counter(), Counter({None: 1})]
reference                   [Counter(), Counter({None: 1}), Counter(), Counter()]
subtract_neighbors  wrong   [Counter(), Counter({None: 1}), Counter(), Counter({None: 1})]
loop                correct [Counter(), Counter({None: 1}), Counter(), Counter()]
fun                 correct [Counter(), Counter({None: 1}), Counter(), Counter()]
```

Code doing the above checks ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLbjtMwEH3vV8xbYuquaBcQW6kPCe/8QBRFjjvZjZTYke0IEOLbyzh2Li0CYSWyZ85cz8zww71p9fx5MLfbFRsw2KBBJTHN2HkHdASHmoPkcIULZJPKoBuNgsJDh1Qwgunap/VBMBKui7BPNwBjUO52Pokda2eEdJXC9vWt1sb@dzbhc9U@h4zBOq2HxT0nr6Kcno02IKBVkAXIn7YBpR3kq8afmpzs2HtfsQDYWfzTTMBhMr0Dou907aFesPxJDAOqa1qzbSN5qLsZ1V3ZWXE@llHaX6AXQ0o8cdIfzyUHIeXYj51wmObsMV5jdA9Sdx1K12ploe0HbRx80aNyaALe0stp3S3oGjIY6AGNcERbxCk9hR6VtJ7VmDKuB9@Fzh8HGfR@JuFF7nxHk3Jo3RqmeD5y@ED/xxd@@lQG04Jk/@Hh9D5eMxL7SGm55mfxVSssWQnv4DRl8PPO/LynVIHXwbTKpQn85WRwSYhgtuyLb9aHmJpep2/Qjp2j6r0@jfZxn4KLXZm5Xxr8PtBMyDXEuMOkNoZAhdYzM1eZ/GMFHzyimPg65hovc0rvDck3o9XrNmigpEl@@sKfqkqJHqvqfHz5RVRs4vMYkW2IZLfbbw)):

```
def reference(A):
    a, b, c, d = A
    return [a, b-(a), c-(a+(b-a)), d-(a+(b-a)+(c-(a+(b-a)))) ]

def subtract_neighbors(A):
    a, b, c, d = A
    return [a, b-a, c-b, d-c]

def loop(A):
    B = []
    for a in A:
        if not B:
            b = sumB = a
        else:
            b = a - sumB
            sumB = sumB + b
        B.append(b)
    return B

def fun(A):
    B = A[:1]
    B += map(sub, A[1:], accumulate(B))
    return B

from collections import Counter
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import sub

funcs = [
    reference,
    subtract_neighbors,
    loop,
    fun,
]

tests = [
    [31, 41, 59,26],
    [1, 1, 1e-20, 1e-20],
    [Counter(), Counter([None])] * 2,
]

for A in tests:
    print('                        A =', A)
    for func in funcs:
        result = func(A)
        if func is reference:
            expect = result
            correctness = '       '
        else:
            correctness = 'correct' if result == expect else 'wrong  '
        print(f'{func.__name__:19}', correctness, result)
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggest by the guys on the comments, this is the simplest and fastest solution:

```
A = [5, 9, 3, 8]
B = [x - y for x, y in zip(A, [0] + A)]
```

This outputs:

```
B
[5, 4, -6, 5]
```

Comment: The use of `sum()` causes a quadratic runtime.

Comment: Given that `B` will always be length `i` at any given step in the algorithm, you shouldn't need to slice it; `B.append(A[i] - sum(B))` should work just fine (aside from the whole `O(n**2)` runtime issue).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You don't even need `sum()`, if you're careful with the algebra. See my answer.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark: Hah. I noticed the same thing, but began composing my answer before you posted (and SO didn't inform me of the new answers as I was typing, boo), so yeah, ended up with essentially the same solution.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Great minds think alike! (or do fools seldom differ?) :)

Comment: @leonardo_vaz -- By the way, to cut down on the runtime, create a separate variable that keeps track of the sum, and update it on each iteration of the `for` loop. Sorry for not suggesting a fix earlier.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right - I didn't think about the computational complexity in my first answer - I'll fix that. Also, as you mentioned in your answer @BrokenBenchmark, the algebra can be simplified to B = [a, b-a, c-b, d-c], which makes it much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

**You can also do it like this**

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [A[0]]+[A[i+1]-A[i] for i in range(len(A)-1)]
```